# Passing 1 to many parameters of same object type

Tags: java, generics, netbeans, overriding, variadic-functions

I need to build a set of input for different workflows using 1 or more outputs from previous workflows, when i do this

```
public interface InputBuilder<I extends SwfInput, O extends SwfOutput> {

    public I buildInput(O... output);
}


public class SwfAuthorisationInputBuilder implements InputBuilder {

    @Override
    public SwfAuthorisationInput buildInput(SwfOutput swfEventInitOutput) {

        SwfEventInitOutput output = (SwfEventInitOutput ) swfEventInitOutput;
        SwfAuthorisationInput authorisationInput = oddFactory.newInstance(SwfAuthorisationInput.class);
        authorisationInput.setNetworkEvent(output.getNetworkEvent());

        return authorisationInput;
    }
```

I am getting and error and Netbeans tip fix gives me this. What am i doing wrong here ?

```
  @Override
        public SwfInput buildInput(SwfOutput... output) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
```

this is the exact error

> method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

How can i avoid casting here ?

```
  @Override
        public SwfAuthorisationInput buildInput(SwfOutput... output) {
            SwfEventInitOutput swfEventInitOutput = (SwfEventInitOutput ) output[0];
            SwfLocationDetectionOutput swfLocationDetectionOutput = (SwfLocationDetectionOutput) output[1];


            SwfAuthorisationInput authorisationInput = oddFactory.newInstance(SwfAuthorisationInput.class);
            authorisationInput.setNetworkEvent(swfEventInitOutput.getNetworkEvent());

            return authorisationInput;
        }
```

Comment: Aside: variadic methods allow you to pass *zero or more* parameters, not one or more. If you want to enforce one or more at compile time, you need to have a single `O firstOutput` parameter before the `O... otherOutputs` - and then handle all of them somehow in your method.

Comment: "I am getting an error" - Please post the exact error. Also, you are using raw types since you do not bind the generic parameters when implementing the interface (`... implements InputBuilder<SwfAuthorisationInput, SwfOutput>` is probably what you want).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
buildInput(SwfOutput swfEventInitOutput)
```

and

```
buildInput(SwfOutput... swfEventInitOutput)
```

are the different method *signatures* (the method's name and the parameter types in Java). If you want to override a method, you have to *exactly* * specify a signature from the parent class.

---

As I can see, you need only one element of this array. If so, you could pull out it from the array checking the array's size before:

```
swfEventInitOutput element = swfEventInitOutput.length > 0 ? swfEventInitOutput[0] : null;
if(element != null) { ... }
```

Another way is to iterate over the array and perform such actions for an each element:

```
for (swfEventInitOutput element : swfEventInitOutput) { ... }
```

---

In addition, I would suggest you specify generic types when you're implementing the `InputBuilder` interface. It helps you to avoid castings (which you did) inside overridden methods.

A positive side here is that you used bounded generics types, it has prevented from `Object...` (or `Object[]`).

Comment: How can i avoid casting , in the implementation of InputBuilder class i know exactly the SwfOutput implementations (1 or more ) but it wont allow me to define it as such- gives me the error method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Comment: @spakai, e.g. `InputBuilder<SubSwfInput, SubSwfOutput>` and `SubSwfOutput...` in the signature

Comment: ok i missed giving one detail , that is SwfEventInitOutput and SwfLocationDetectionOutput implements SwfOutput but they have different fields from each other , hence I believe I can't run away from casting

Comment: @spakai, addressing to array's elements like you did (`output[1]`) is hard coding and will lead to a plenty of errors in the future

Comment: @spakai, that is a poor architecture, your method takes an array of `SwfOutput` elements and normally you are not aware of the element order in that array. You should operate only with methods provided by the interface. Otherwise, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: agreed it looks bad . Thanks.

Comment: Might be a builder pattern will be more suitable

Comment: public interface Builder<I extends SwfInput> {
    public I build();
}

Comment: I've improved the design (i think) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39989893/using-a-fluent-builder-pattern-without-inner-static-classes-for-workflow