# Using a fluent builder pattern without inner static classes for workflow

Tags: java, design-patterns

This is a continuation from what I was working in [Passing 1 to many parameters of same object type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768434/passing-1-to-many-parameters-of-same-object-type)

I've gotten good feedback on that , I believe i have the improved the design . The whole code is at https://github.com/spakai/flow_input_builder

The requirement is simple : -

I need to build a set of input for different workflows using 1 or more outputs from previous workflows

I have a set of interfaces

```
public interface SwfInput {

}

public interface SwfOutput {

}

public interface Workflow<I extends SwfInput, O extends SwfOutput> {

    public O execute(I input);
}

public interface Builder<I extends SwfInput> {
    public I build();

}
```

Now , Say I have 3 flows which gets executed in sequence FlowA->FlowB->FlowC

FlowC needs mandatory output from FlowB but only optionally from FlowA

so I have a implementation for FlowCBuilder

```
public class FlowCInputBuilder implements Builder<FlowCInput> {

    private final FlowBOutput mandatoryflowBOutput;
    private FlowAOutput optionalflowAOutput;

    public FlowAOutput getOptionalflowAOutput() {
        return optionalflowAOutput;
    }

    public FlowCInputBuilder setOptionalflowAOutput(FlowAOutput optionalflowAOutput) {
        this.optionalflowAOutput = optionalflowAOutput;
        return this;
    }

    public FlowCInputBuilder(FlowBOutput mandatoryflowBOutput) {
        this.mandatoryflowBOutput = mandatoryflowBOutput;
    }

    @Override
    public FlowCInput build() {

        FlowCInput input = new FlowCInput();
        input.setMandatoryFromFlowB(mandatoryflowBOutput.getOutput1FromB());

        if (optionalflowAOutput != null) {
            input.setOptionalFromFlowA(optionalflowAOutput.getOutput2FromA());
        }

        return input;       

    }


}
```

one test i have written shows an example usage

```
 FlowBOutput mandatoryflowBOutput = new FlowBOutput();

 mandatoryflowBOutput.setOutput1FromB("iNeedThis");
 FlowAOutput optionalflowAOutput = new FlowAOutput();
 FlowCInput input =  new FlowCInputBuilder(mandatoryflowBOutput)
                .setOptionalflowAOutput(optionalflowAOutput)
                .build();
```

I have not used static inner class for the Builder pattern.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: ah, the question is , whether the design makes sense, and whether there is a better way of doing this , and if it is ok not use static inner class in the builder pattern?

Comment: A static member class is, for all intents and purposes, the same thing as a top level class (just moved around for packaging convenience).  So, if you want to use an actual top level class as a Builder, go for it.  Many people would say that since the Builder is meant to work only with the class whose objects it builds, that it is best packaged as a static member class of that class.  But you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use static inner class. The key point of using this approach is that, the inner can directly access private properties of the object being constructed. This helps eliminating duplicated code since the builder does not need to maintain a long list of temporary state for the constructing. So, your code can be rewritten like this:

```
public class FlowCInput {
    private int output1FromB; // suppose that it is int
    private String output2FromA; // suppose that it is String
    private FlowCInput() { }
    //...

    public static class FlowCInputBuilder implements Builder<FlowCInput> {
        private final FlowCInput result;

        public FlowCInputBuilder(FlowBOutput mandatoryflowBOutput) {
            result = new FlowCInput();
            // output1FromB is private but still accessed from here
            result.output1FromB = mandatoryflowBOutput.getOutput1FromB();
        }

        public FlowCInputBuilder setOptionalflowAOutput(FlowAOutput optionalflowAOutput) {
            // same for output2FromA
            result.output2FromA = optionalflowAOutput.getOutput2FromA();
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public FlowCInput build() {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, the builder now holds only a `FlowCInput` object, it does not unnecessarily hold `mandatoryflowBOutput` and `optionalflowAOutput` as before.